Gradle Plugin and AWS Codeartifact
I am trying to figure out how I can download gradle plugins from aws code artifact private repository.
Is it possible to download a plugin from the a private repository?
If it is possible how can I configure the credentials for the private repository ?

AWS have published instructions on how to integrate CodeArtifact with Gradle.
In overview, their suggested approach is to:

Set up and obtain appropriate user credentials
Install the AWS CLI utility and associate the user credentials with it
Register an environment variable which obtains the authorisation token needed for repository access

You can then register the repository in your settings.gradle (this is for plugin access):
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'my_repo'
            url 'https://my_domain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/maven/my_repo/'
            credentials {
                username 'aws'
                password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}

Plugins can then be retrieved by id in the plugins block of the build.gradle file.

I have tried this. but IntelliJ is not able to access CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN. the token is having value null

You need to set up your environment variable. Follow all the instructions thoroughly.
